# Attempting to enable encryption on DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Trying to use encryption at rest on a DynamoDB table.

The table is being created using Cloud Formation, and encrypted using the following settings:

```
SSESpecification:
    SSEEnabled: true
```

The table indicates that it is indeed encrypted when checking the table overview from AWS Console.

However, when looking at an item inside the table, it's showing as plain text and not encrypted at all.

Does anyone know what is going on? From reading the documentation, the encryption should be activated when the table loads using those settings outlined, I might be missing something though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encryption at rest is fully transparent to the user with all DynamoDB queries working seamlessly on encrypted data

[From their blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-encryption-at-rest-for-dynamodb/)

> You simply enable encryption when you create a new table and DynamoDB
>   takes care of the rest. Your data (tables, local secondary indexes,
>   and global secondary indexes) will be encrypted using AES-256 and a
>   service-default AWS Key Management Service (KMS) key. The encryption
>   adds no storage overhead and is completely transparent; you can
>   insert, query, scan, and delete items as before. The team did not
>   observe any changes in latency after enabling encryption and running
>   several different workloads on an encrypted DynamoDB table.

Regarding verification, the blog mentions one way to verify that the data is encrypted. It involves measuring a side effect that would only exist if the table is being encrypted. Admittedly it is not direct verification but I believe it is as close as we can come for now.

> When my compliance team asks me to show them how DynamoDB uses the key
>   to encrypt the data, I can create a AWS CloudTrail trail, insert an
>   item, and then scan the table to see the calls to the AWS KMS API.
>   Here’s an extract from the trail:

```
{
  "eventTime": "2018-01-24T00:06:34Z",
  "eventSource": "kms.amazonaws.com",
  "eventName": "Decrypt",
  "awsRegion": "us-west-2",
  "sourceIPAddress": "dynamodb.amazonaws.com",
  "userAgent": "dynamodb.amazonaws.com",
  "requestParameters": {
    "encryptionContext": {
      "aws:dynamodb:tableName": "reg-users",
      "aws:dynamodb:subscriberId": "1234567890"
    }
  },
  "responseElements": null,
  "requestID": "7072def1-009a-11e8-9ab9-4504c26bd391",
  "eventID": "3698678a-d04e-48c7-96f2-3d734c5c7903",
  "readOnly": true,
  "resources": [
    {
      "ARN": "arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:1234567890:key/e7bd721d-37f3-4acd-bec5-4d08c765f9f5",
      "accountId": "1234567890",
      "type": "AWS::KMS::Key"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. Do you know how to verify the _data_ is encrypted (besides seeing that the table is labelled encrypted)? Also, is this transparent to any user viewing items in the table? Just wondering how effective that is supposed to be...

Comment: Updated answer to address verification. You also asked about transparency to any user. In short, yes. I think its worth mentioning that for any user with permission to access the table, the encryption is transparent. Any user without permission will be denied access as usual.